# Maximum call stack size exceeded error / Properly writing constructors

Tags: google-chrome, recursion, constructor, stack-size

Firstly, I got a 'maximum call stack size exceeded' error on some JavaScript code I'll be posting below, and I'm not sure where it's coming from. I don't think I'm calling anything recursively, and I couldn't find any other cause of the error from looking around. I'm using Chrome to execute the program, and the only details I can get out of the console are 'Vector Vector Vector Vector Vector Vector Vector...' etc. I think this means that the Vector function is recursively calling itself, but, again, I can't figure out where that's happening. So, firstly, here's the Vector function:

```
function Vector(top,left) { //a vector constructor, with all necessary vector operations
    this.top = top; //the 'top' component, which points down
    this.left = left;   //the 'left' component, which points right
    this.in = 0;        //the 'in' component, which points out of the screen
    this.magnitude = Math.sqrt(this.top*this.top+this.left*this.left);  //the magnitude of the vector
    this.reverse = new Vector(-this.top,-this.left);                            //the vector that points opposite of this vector
    this.unit = this.Scale(1/this.magnitude);                                       //the unit vector pointing in this vector's direction
    this.Scale = Scale;         //multiplying vectors by a constant
    this.Add = Add;             //easier vector addition
    this.Subtract = Subtract;   //and subtraction
    this.Dot = Dot;             //a dot product operation
    this.Cross = Cross;         //the cross product of two planar vectors; it returns the 'in' component of the resulting vector
    this.Project = Project;     //the projetion of the parameter vector onto this vector
        function Scale(scalar) {return new Vector(scalar*this.top,scalar*this.left);}
        function Add(vector) {return new Vector(this.top+vector.top,this.left+vector.left);}
        function Subtract(vector) {return new Vector(this.top-vector.top,this.left-vector.left);}   //the abovedescribed methods
        function Dot(vector) {return this.top*vector.top+this.left*vector.left;}
        function Cross(vector) {return this.top*vector.left-this.left*vector.top;}
        function Project(vector) {return this.Scale(this.Dot(vector)/Math.pow(this.magnitude,2))}
    }

var zeroVector = new Vector(0,0);
```

And here's the full code. Feel free to completely ignore it, though maybe something will be blatantly obvious to you which was impeccably hidden from me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>temp</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas
        id="canvas"
        height="768px"
        width="1366px"
        style="position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;"
        />
</body>

<script>
/*------------------------------------------------------------Composition Center--------------------------------------------------*/ {
    window.onload = run;    //it'll start running as soon as it's started up

    var interval;   //the interval variable for the 'run' function

    function run() {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            for (i=0; i!=0; i++) {
                var Point = point;
                var vPrime = zeroVector;
                var netForce = zeroVector;
                for (j=0; j!=0; j++) {
                    var Edge = edge;
                    updateCollision(Point,Edge);
                    }
                updatePosition(Point);
                updateVelocity(Point);
                draw();
                }
            },16);
        }
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ }



/*-------------------------------------------------------------Physics Engine------------------------------------------------------*/ {
                                //--Constructors--//
    function PointObject(mass,top,left) {   //a point object
        this.mass = mass;                               //mass
        this.position = new Vector(top,left);   //position
        this.velocity = zeroVector;             //velocity
        this.near = nullEdge;                       //a memory tool which stores the edge the point is close to
        }
    function Rectangle(top,left,height,width) { //a rectangle that'll be solid, but not affected by gravity or anything
        this.position = new Vector(top,left);
        this.height = height;   //self-explanatory
        this.width = width;
        }
    function Edge(start,end) {
        this.start = start;                     //the start point (vector)
        this.end = end;                         //end point (vector)
        this.vector = end.Subtract(start);  //the vector pointing from the start to the end point of the edge
        this.RUN = new Vector(this.vector.left,-this.vector.top).unit;  //the RIGHT pointing UNIT NORMAL vector to the edge vector
        this.rightPermeable = false;    //whether or not the edge can be passed through from the right to the left
        this.leftPermeable = true;      //or from the left to the right
        }
                                //--Objects--//
    var base = new Rectangle(3/4*768,33,768/4,1300);                    //the main base solid
    var point = new PointObject(1,base.position.top-201,1366/2);    //the point object at the center of this whole ordeal
    var edge = new Edge(new Vector(base.position.top,base.position.left+base.width),base.position); //a test edge. they'll be auto-assembled later

    var nullEdge = new Edge(zeroVector,zeroVector);

    var deltaT = .01;   //standard time interval

                                //--Loop o' Physics--//
    //Update Collision
        function updateCollision(Point,edge) {  //check if any points are crossing edges and deal with that
            var startToPoint = Point.position.Subtract(edge.start); //the vector from the start point of the edge to the tested point
            if (edge.rightPermeable && edge.vector.Cross(startToPoint) < 0) {return "Negatory.";}   //if it could only approach from a permeable side, stop testing
            if (edge.leftPermeable && edge.vector.Cross(startToPoint) > 0) {return "Negatory.";}
            var projection = edge.vector.Project(startToPoint);     //the projection of that vector onto the edge vector
            if (projection.Dot(edge.vector) < 0) {return "Negatory.";}  //if it's not pointing in the same dircetion as the edge vector, it's not gonna hit the edge
            var distance = startToPoint.Subtract(projection);           //the normal vector to the edge that points to the Point
            var velocity = distance.Project(Point.velocity);            //the component of the point's velocity orthogonal to the edge
            if (distance.Dot(velocity) >= 0) {return "Negatory.";}  //if the orthogonal velocity component is pointing 'to the point,' it won't collide
            var specificT = distance.magnitude/velocity.magnitude;  //the time it'll take for the point to hit the edge, if it continues with it's current velocity
            if (deltaT <= specificT) {return "Negatory.";}  //if the point can't move far enough to cover the distance, it won't collide
            //at this point, the collision will happen
            Point.near = edge;  //have the point remember that it collided with this edge, so it won't have to be totally re-tested for normal forces
            Point.position = Point.position.Add(Point.velocity.Scale(specificT)).Add(distance.Scale(.0001));    //move the point just a wee bit away from the edge
            vPrime = Point.velocity.Add(velocity.reverse);  //impulse away the velocity orthogonal to the edge
            Point.velocity = Point.velocity.Scale(0);   //zero the current velocity
            }
    //Update Position
        function updatePosition(Point) {Point.position = Point.position.Add(Point.velocity.Scale(deltaT));} //d=vt, essentially
    //Update Velocity
        function updateVelocity(Point) {    //via forces
            var gravity = new Vector(20,0); //gravity... hobviously
            netForce = netForce.Add(gravity);   //add up all the current forces to get the right normal force
            if (Point.near != nullEdge) {   //calculating normal force, so it needs to be near an edge
                var startToPoint = Point.position.Subtract(Point.near.start);
                var projection = Point.near.vector.Project(startToPoint);   //same stuff as earlier
                var distance = startToPoint.Subtract(projection);
                if (distance.magnitude <= .01) {                                                                //if it's very near to the edge
                    normalForce = distance.Project(netForce.reverse);                                   //exert enough force to cancel anything going into the edge
                    if (normalForce.Dot(distance) > 0) {netForce = netForce.Add(normalForce);}  //if it is indeed going into the edge
                    } else if (distance.magnitude > 1) {Point.near = nullEdge;} //it's not near the edge any more
                }
            Point.velocity = Point.velocity.Add(netForce.Scale(deltaT/Point.mass)); //v=at, essentially
            }
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ }



/*----------------------------------------------------Graphics----------------------------------------------------------------------*/ {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"); //the means for drawing all this

    PointObject.prototype.Draw = function() {   //the draw method for point objects
        c.fillStyle = "#000000";    //a black square with the point at its center pixel
        c.fillRect(this.position.left-2,this.position.top-2,5,5);
        }
    Rectangle.prototype.Draw = function() { //draw method for rectangles
        c.fillStyle = "#c0c0c0";    //a grey rectangle; the position is the top left corner
        c.fillRect(this.position.left,this.position.top,this.width,this.height);
        }

    function draw() {   //draws everything
        c.clearRect(0,0,1366,768);  //clear the screen
        base.Draw();                    //paint stuff
        point.Draw();
        }
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ }



/*------------------------------------------------------------Math Tools-------------------------------------------------------------*/ {
                                //--Vector Tools--//
    function Vector(top,left) { //a vector constructor, with all necessary vector operations
        this.top = top; //the 'top' component, which points down
        this.left = left;   //the 'left' component, which points right
        this.in = 0;        //the 'in' component, which points out of the screen
        this.magnitude = Math.sqrt(this.top*this.top+this.left*this.left);  //the magnitude of the vector
        this.reverse = new Vector(-this.top,-this.left);                            //the vector that points opposite of this vector
        this.unit = this.Scale(1/this.magnitude);                                       //the unit vector pointing in this vector's direction
        this.Scale = Scale;         //multiplying vectors by a constant
        this.Add = Add;             //easier vector addition
        this.Subtract = Subtract;   //and subtraction
        this.Dot = Dot;             //a dot product operation
        this.Cross = Cross;         //the cross product of two planar vectors; it returns the 'in' component of the resulting vector
        this.Project = Project;     //the projetion of the parameter vector onto this vector
            function Scale(scalar) {return new Vector(scalar*this.top,scalar*this.left);}
            function Add(vector) {return new Vector(this.top+vector.top,this.left+vector.left);}
            function Subtract(vector) {return new Vector(this.top-vector.top,this.left-vector.left);}   //the abovedescribed methods
            function Dot(vector) {return this.top*vector.top+this.left*vector.left;}
            function Cross(vector) {return this.top*vector.left-this.left*vector.top;}
            function Project(vector) {return this.Scale(this.Dot(vector)/Math.pow(this.magnitude,2))}
        }

    var zeroVector = new Vector(0,0);
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ }
</script>

</html>
```

Anyway, second thing is about how I've written some bits of the Vector constructor, which may possibly somehow be causing my error. At various points I use 'new Vector()' in the properties and methods of the function, and I don't know if that's illegal or not. I think I've done it before without error, but I'm not sure.

Also, for the 'magnitude,' 'reverse,' and 'unit' properties, should I rephrase them as methods? I think the way they are they're being locked into the magnitude/reverse/unit vector of the vector as it is created, so if the top or left properties are changed, they'll return incorrect values. The only reason I haven't changed them yet is that they strike me more as properties than methods, just conceptually. It hasn't caused any problems yet or anything; just wondering.

If you want this on JSFiddle or something else like that, I'd be happy to oblige you.